# How do I save a captured .mov file to the custom album using custom url?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I would like to save a captured .mov video file to the custom album using custom URL, something like that `".../10-9-2018.mov"`. My problem is that I know how to save to the album, but I don't know how to save it using custom url to an album.

Comment: In iOS you do not have to use a url to save a video or photo to an album. It is all abstracted behind the PhotoLibrary. There is no "Folder"-System like in Android.

Comment: @MarcelT, I do agree, but there is something like this. Because if I download a photo from Instagram - I'll see it in the folder Instagram and in all photos. And I have already implemented it in my project, but I don't know who to save the video with custom URL: "/12.05.2018.mov". So in the future, I would be able to parse everything and display this video if I choose this date in my app.